# Pending operations in playwright on nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, testing, playwright

I'm trying to get a new page at the moment of clicking on the link:

```
await test.step(`Step name`, async () => {
    const [newPage] = await Promise.all([ 
        context.waitForEvent('page'), 
        page.click('//span[normalize-space(@title)=\'Bup\']')
    ]);
}
```

And I get this page. Further operations with this instance are successful. But after 30 seconds the test ends with the following error:

```
Timeout of 30000ms exceeded.
Pending operations: 
    - browserContext.waitForEvent at "path to the file":48:21
    - at <unknown>
```

I will assume that it is related to a promise, but I do not understand what exactly the problem is. Help is needed.
**Playwright v14.0, nodejs v16.7.0**.
I run the tests with the following command: `npx playwright test tests/diag.spec.mjs --headed`

*A strange observation. When I run it in debug mode, there is no such error*
:

```
PWDEBUG=1 npx playwright test tests/diag.spec.mjs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer, but it's a little weird. You need to increase the timeout in the playwright config:

https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/8268

Also you can add `test.slow()` https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-test#test-slow